# Is this function always greater than zero?

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, maxima-minima

I have this function $$f(\lambda)= \sum_i p_i\cdot\frac{\lambda_i^2}{w_i^2} - \frac{\left(\sum_i g_i\cdot \lambda_i\right)^2}{\left(\sum_i g_i\cdot w_i\right)^2},$$ where $p_i, g_i$ and $w_i$ are probabilities that sum to $1$, $\lambda_i's$ are greater than $0$.

I conjecture this function is always greater or equal to zero, but could not prove it.
Any suggestions?

Edit: As @Youem showed, this function is not always greater than 0. However, this new function does $$f(\lambda)= \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{g_i\lambda_i^2}{w_i \sum_{k=1}^Ng_k\cdot w_k} - \frac{\left(\sum_i g_i\cdot \lambda_i\right)^2}{\left(\sum_i g_i\cdot w_i\right)^2}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general, for example $n=2$, $p_1 = 1$, $p_2 = 0$, $g_1 = 0$, $g_2 = 1$, $w_1 = 1/2$, $w_2 = 1/2$, $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = 2$

$$f(\lambda) = 4 - 4\times 4 = -12$$

Comment: Right! I must have made a mistake somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: What about $$f(\lambda )= \sum_i \frac{g_i\cdot\lambda_i^2}{w_i\left(\sum_ jg_j\cdot w_j\right)} - \frac{\left(\sum_i g_i\cdot \lambda_i\right)^2}{\left(\sum_i g_i\cdot w_i\right)^2},$$ adding the fact g, w are nonzero?

Comment: Yes this function should be positive. Use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Youem!

Comment: If anyone is interested, I in the end used the Sedrakyan's lemma: $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{u_i^2}{v_i} \geq \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\right)^2 }{\sum_{i=1}^n v_i}$ to the first term and shows $f(\lambda)$ above is always greater or equal to zero.